Activating GPS in Android using Delphi
This is my code below which I use to enable GPS in Delphi. The problem is that the GPS automatically enabled on the phone ONLY the first time the application is launched right after installation. After that, I always have to turn it on manually.
The question is, how to trigger at least a message that will make the user have to turn on the GPS himself ?
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
 permAccess = 'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION';
  permCoarse = 'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION';
begin

  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permAccess],
    procedure(const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray)
    begin
      if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
        { activate or deactivate the location sensor }
        LocationSensor1.Active:=true


      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Problem');
      end;
    end);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

